# Subquery in FROM clause fails in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I stumbled upon a strange behavior of MySQL (v.8) when trying to run a nested subquery in the FROM clause. The (relevant part of the) schema of the sample database I am using is as follows:

[image]

The following two queries run identically on SQL Server:

```
SELECT SUM(tot) as total
 FROM (
     SELECT 
        SUM(OD.quantityOrdered * OD.priceEach) as tot,
        C.customerNumber
     FROM customers C
     INNER JOIN orders O ON C.customerNumber = O.customerNumber
     INNER JOIN orderdetails OD ON O.orderNumber = OD.orderNumber
     GROUP BY O.orderNumber, C.customerNumber
) AS CO
GROUP BY CO.customerNumber;
```

and

```
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT SUM(tot) as total
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                (
                    SELECT  SUM(OD.quantityOrdered * OD.priceEach)
                    FROM orderdetails OD 
                    WHERE OD.orderNumber = O.orderNumber
                ) AS tot
            FROM orders O
            WHERE O.customerNumber = C.customerNumber
        ) AS ORD
  ) AS total
FROM customers AS C;
```

However, on MySQL, the first one runs fine, while the second one results in an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'C.customerNumber' in 'where clause'
```

I will appreciate any clues about why this is happening. *Please note* that I am mostly interested not in workarounds or other ways to implement this query, but in understanding the reasons why the nested query fails.

Comment: I don't see any table or alias called `C` in your second query.

Comment: @SalmanA The very bottom line: `FROM customers AS C`.

Comment: Inner nested subqueries do not "know" the outer aliases in tsql. Is there some CTE before the select? I doubt this runs on sql server.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis One can paste both queries [here](https://www.sqlprep.com/sc_dailychallenge/daily-challenge-19/) to test (ubfortunately, that site's certificate expired just today, but one can still go through), and that site uses MS SQL connection, AFAIK. For MySQL, I was testing on a local database. But thanks for the hint, that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

C table alias  in  not in scope for the suquery
try refactoring the query using a join

eg

```
select  c.customerNumber,  t.my_tot 
FROM customers AS C
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT  O.customerNumber, SUM(OD.quantityOrdered * OD.priceEach) my_tot
  FROM orderdetails OD 
  INNER JOIN orders O ON  OD.orderNumber = O.orderNumber
  GROUP BY O.customerNumber
) t on t.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
```

or

```
select  t.my_tot 
FROM customers AS C
INNER JOIN (

  SELECT  O.customerNumber, SUM(OD.quantityOrdered * OD.priceEach) my_tot
  FROM orderdetails OD 
  INNER JOIN orders O ON  OD.orderNumber = O.orderNumber
  GROUP BY O.customerNumber
) t on t.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But more important for me is the cause of failure. Do you know any references on scoping rules for table aliases? Thanks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin   ..which db you are really using ?   .. mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  ... for the scope .. is not related  to the alias  . the same situation happen using the table  name  ... the inner subqqury can't see/jknow  the others table or alias  name  ..  when you need you should apply the contion for join  on outers table joined  this the inner subquery but at outer level

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
SELECT 
  (   
      select SUM(tot) as total from

          (   
            SELECT 
                (
                    SELECT  SUM(OD.quantityOrdered * OD.priceEach)
                    FROM orderdetails OD 
                    WHERE OD.orderNumber = O.orderNumber
                ) AS tot,customerNumber
            FROM orders O
           )  as ord      
            WHERE ord.customerNumber = C.customerNumber        
  ) AS total
FROM customers AS C;
```

Your customers table  not in scope of subquery where you used in where condition `WHERE O.customerNumber = C.customerNumber` so  i made alias of that
and then later level i used same condition where customers table has scope

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. But so far I could not figure out why. It looks very close to my second (non-working) query, the level of nesting of `C.customerNumber` is the same, the only difference seems to be an extra `customerNumber` field in the `SELECT` list for `orders`. If you could add a few lines of explanation why your query works, that would've been awesome.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin i added explanation actually its all about scope

Answer (score 1):

You have a correlated subquery in the second case.  However, the correlation clause is *two levels deep*.

Many databases will still recognize `c`, even when nested multiple levels.  However, MySQL (and Oracle and I think MS Access) is a database that limits correlation clauses to one level deep.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, and this is coming from a stackoverflow expert like @Gordon Linoff so I rated this answer above